# What types of speed radar detectors are illegal in France?

Tags: driving, france

I'm traveling in France, and I've been vaguely told that some radar detectors are illegal. What types of radar detectors are illegal in France?

Ideally I'd like to know the sanctions as well. I'm especially interested in radar detector applications on smartphones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I am not a lawyer; I am not your lawyer**

In France, the [*Code de la Route* (Article R413-15)](http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=DE796BB259DC634E9E598A6E500B2BE3.tpdila21v_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000025111528&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006074228&dateTexte=20150702) outlaws the possession of devices that detect or disturb, or are intended to detect or disturb, the operation of devices or systems that record or regulate road traffic, or allow evasion of road traffic offenses.

This Article was last amended on 3 January 2012, and it is punishable by a fine of up to  €1,500, confiscation of the device, and confiscation of the vehicle.

The law is not prescriptive about such devices, and this is likely intentionally so. This Article is technology-agnostic, and would apply to any device with such a purpose. **You can therefore assume that *all* speed radar detectors are illegal.**

Comment: Adding to your answer, even carrying a GPS device with a database of radars is illegal in France.

Comment: For information, a common workaround on GPS is to indicate a speed radar as a 'danger zone'